# MongoDB db.collection.find() operator

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following structure in MongoDB. Is it possible to find only the information that is under "C" maybe adding a condition like "ID:2"?

```
{
ID:1
Data: 123
Data1:1234
B:[
   ID:1
   Data:123
   Data1:1234
   C:[
      ID:1
      Data:123
      Data1:12345
     ]
  ]
}


{
ID:2
Data: 123
Data1:1234
B:[
   ID:2
   Data:123
   Data1:1234
   C:[
      ID:2
      Data:123
      Data1:12345
     ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find information that is under C"? If you want to return from query only field C you can use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Comment: I mean all the fields: ID, Data and Data1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({'B.C.ID':2},{'B.C':1})
```

should do the trick.

Comment: what about if I have in C all data null at ID:2 and at ID:1 I have only Data1:null. I want to find only records with all data null. How I am doing this? I tried with db.collection.find({C:null}) but I am retriving the data with partial null too.

Comment: Please read the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/). Your use cases are documented in high detail.